# Use backend function to return string of all list values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, backend

I have two files being *frontend.py* and *backend.py* and want the front end to call the backend to return a string containing the output of all values across three lists in a single string. The back end must not interact with the user at all (no print, stdout, readline) and the unpacking of the list must be done using a while loop.

When running the frontend I am getting the below error. From my understanding, it is telling me that the index being passed in does not have a corresponding index in the list itself. It doesn't make sense to me as I have printed out the values before they execute and they are accurate.

## **ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frontend.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "frontend.py", line 37, in main
    print(backend.output_all(colours, categories, prices))
  File "backend.py", line 26, in output_all
    message += "Colour: " + list1[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

## **FRONTEND**

```
import sys
import backend

def main():
    colours = backend.init_data_structure()
    categories = backend.init_data_structure()
    prices = backend.init_data_structure()

    sys.stdout.write("MAIN MENU\n")
    sys.stdout.write(backend.menu())
    choice = sys.stdin.readline().strip().upper()

    while choice != "Q":

        if choice == "A":
            sys.stdout.write("What is the colour of the item?\n")
            colour = sys.stdin.readline().strip().upper()
            backend.add_record(colours, colour)

            sys.stdout.write("What category does the item belong to?\n")
            sys.stdout.write("[1] Trousers\n")
            sys.stdout.write("[2] Skirts\n")
            sys.stdout.write("[3] Blouses\n")
            sys.stdout.write("[4] Sales\n")
            category = int(sys.stdin.readline())
            backend.add_record(categories, category)

            sys.stdout.write("What is the price of the item?\n$")
            price = float(sys.stdin.readline())
            backend.add_record(prices, price)

            sys.stdout.write("How would you like to proceed?\n")
            sys.stdout.write(backend.menu())
            choice = sys.stdin.readline().strip().upper()
            
        elif choice == "D":
             print(backend.output_all(colours, categories, prices))
            
main()
```

## **BACKEND**

```
def init_data_structure():
    return []

def add_record(list_name, data):
    list_name.append(data)

def list_length(data_structure):
    length = len(data_structure)
    return int(length)

def get_value_at_index(list_name, index):
    return data_structure[index]

def output_all(list1, list2, list3):
    message = ""
    l = list_length(list1)
    i = 0
    while i <= l:
        message += "Record # " + str(i)
        message += "-------------------"
        message += "Colour: " + get_value_at_index(list1, i)
        message += "Category: " + str(get_value_at_index(list1, i))
        message += "Price: " + str(get_value_at_index(list1, i))
        message += "\n"
        i += 1
        
    return message
         
def menu():
    menu = "---------------\n"
    menu += "[A]dd Record\n"
    menu += "[D]isplay All Records\n"
    menu += "[Q]uit\n"
    menu += "---------------\n"
    menu += "Your Selection: "
    return menu
```

I have tried moving the code all to the front end, have rewritten it to output without a loop, and many other modifications to try and locate the issue.

I am new to programming and this is for an assignment, it would do a lot for my learning to know where I've gone wrong here. I have always been able to debug and locate my errors and learn from them using online resources like StackOverflow but this one has me stumped.

Comment: Why, are you using `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`?

Comment: Requirement of my course, they are teaching us programming concepts that are applicable to multiple languages. A print is python specific and automatically converts values to strings the lecturer wants us to use sys to be concious of data types we are manipulating and passing back and forth.

Comment: Consider the list `x = [0, 1, 2, 3]`. Then you say `length = len(x)`. What happens if you do `x[length]`?

Comment: You are looping till `<= list_length` which will result in the error on the last index. Use `< list_length` instead.

Comment: Anyway, please always post a [mcve], don't just dump your whole code here. Thanks for posting the full error message including the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

@mushroomator thank you, it was because I was using <= list_length and not < list_length.

```
def output_all(list1, list2, list3):
message = ""
l = list_length(list1)
i = 0
while i < l:
    message += "Record # " + str(i) + "\n"
    message += "-------------------\n"
    message += "Colour: " + get_value_at_index(list1, i) + "\n"
    message += "Category: " + str(get_value_at_index(list2, i)) + "\n"
    message += "Price: $" + str(get_value_at_index(list3, i)) + "\n"
    message += "\n"
    i += 1

return message
```